# How to subtract second row from first row and generate a output column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a situation, consider the following query :

```
select 
    A.cakename, A.status, B.ordertime
from
    Cake as A
        inner join
    Orders as B on A.cakeid = B.cakeid
```

The output of this query

```
cakename,   status,      ordertime
Apple Pie, available,    2014-03-20 22:34:46
Apple Pie, available,    2014-10-10 04:00:00
Apple Pie, available,    2015-03-20 22:34:46
Brownie,   available,    2014-03-20 22:35:07
Brownie,   available,    2015-05-20 22:35:07
Brownie,   available,    2014-03-26 22:36:07
Brownie,   available,    2015-05-20 14:35:48
Brownie,   available,    2015-05-20 22:35:07
Brownie,   available,    2015-05-10 22:35:07
```

Now I want to subtract the `ordertime row n+1 - ordertime row n` and create a separate column to store the result. For now you can ignore the last row since there will be no next row.

For example: `2014-10-10 04:00:00` - `2014-03-20 22:34:46` this equation will be for first row, and its result will be stored in a new column lets take `difference of consecutive ordertime`. Could anyone give me some pointers to solve this situation ?

If you could help to create a `auto increment column` that will be great because then I can self join and take the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an extra calculated field:

```
select 
A.cakename, A.status, B.ordertime,
(SELECT MAX(ordertime) FROM Orders AS C WHERE C.ordertime < B.ordertime) AS prev
from
Cake as A
    inner join
Orders as B on A.cakeid = B.cakeid
ORDER BY ordertime;
```

but you'll better have an index on `ordertime`:

```
CREATE INDEX ord_ndx ON Orders(ordertime, cakeid);
```

Actually, you can directly calculate [the difference from the previous time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) (assuming it's not NULL; you have to supply a default with IF for that).

## A different way

However, depending on your architecture, you might be better served by adding a column (`previous_order`). When you *insert* an order, you know what you need. See this example using `TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( itemid integer, ordertime timestamp, previous datetime );
CREATE INDEX test_ndx ON test (itemid, ordertime);

CREATE TRIGGER test_set_prev 
    BEFORE INSERT ON test 
    FOR EACH ROW
        SET NEW.previous = (
            SELECT MAX(ordertime) FROM test WHERE itemid = NEW.itemid
        );
```

**Now you table works automatically**. The TIMESTAMP column will auto-update, and so will the `previous` column:

```
insert into test (itemid) values (2);
select sleep(2);
insert into test (itemid) values (2);

+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| itemid | ordertime           | previous            |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      2 | 2015-10-21 09:30:44 | NULL                |
|      2 | 2015-10-21 09:30:46 | 2015-10-21 09:30:44 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

It also works with multiple inserts:

```
insert into test (itemid) values (3), (2), (3);
```

Comment: I modified your query and it is working for me :) Thank you so much

Comment: `select 
    A.cakename,
    A.status,
    B.ordertime,
    (SELECT 
            timestampdiff(month,
                    MAX(ordertime),
                    B.ordertime)
        FROM
            Orders AS C
        WHERE
            C.ordertime < B.ordertime
                and A.cakeid = C.cakeid
        limit 1) AS prev
from
    Cake as A
        inner join
    Orders as B ON A.cakeid = B.cakeid
ORDER BY A.cakename , B.ordertime;` this is the query

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.*,
  IF(@prev IS NULL ,0 , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.ordertime,@prev)) diff,
  @prev = t.ordertime
FROM (
  SELECT 
    A.cakename, A.status, B.ordertime
  FROM Cake as A
  INNER JOIN Orders as B 
  ON A.cakeid = B.cakeid
  ORDER BY ordertime 
) t
```

Comment: sow me proof and post expected result? could you provide sqlfiddle for tests?

Comment: This is a modifed query @Iserni answer and it working for me `select 
    A.cakename,
    A.status,
    B.ordertime,
    (SELECT 
            timestampdiff(month,
                    MAX(ordertime),
                    B.ordertime)
        FROM
            Orders AS C
        WHERE
            C.ordertime < B.ordertime
                and A.cakeid = C.cakeid
        limit 1) AS prev
from
    Cake as A
        inner join
    Orders as B ON A.cakeid = B.cakeid
ORDER BY A.cakename , B.ordertime;`

Comment: I prefer my way. but if you like your solution - that is up to you. I am glad that you have one now.

Comment: Have not tested, but Alex's solution **is** more efficient, requiring one join less, *as long as you order your rows* (previous really means" the row before"). You possibly did not do that, and that is why Alex's solution appears not to be working. I for one am upvoting it :-)